# How to get name (path) of uinput created device

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, uinput

I have successfully set up a small program to create a [uinput](/questions/tagged/uinput) device which I plan to use to automate testing of an application receiving keyboard input events.

I have followed [both](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) [tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710121647/http://www.einfochips.com/download/dash_jan_tip.pdf) as found in this very nice [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/how-to-inject-keystrokes-via-a-shell-script).

When my program creates the uinput device by calling `ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE)` a new device appears in the file system so my application under test can attach to it and wait for events. My target system already has a `/dev/input/event0` device so the new one gets the path `/dev/input/event1`. If I compile and run the program for my desktop system, where there are existing devices `/dev/input/event[0-15]`, when the program is run the new device gets `/dev/input/event16`.

I'd like my program to report the new device name after creating it. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Maybe you can use libudev http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `UI_GET_SYSNAME` (defined in `/usr/include/linux/uinput.h`) if it's available on your platform (Android, for instance, does not define it for some reason). It will give you a name for the device created in `/sys/devices/virtual/input`. Once you know the device in *sysfs*, you can figure out the device(s) created in `/dev/input` by reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623442/how-do-i-determine-the-files-corresponding-to-a-uinput-device).

Use it after calling `UI_DEV_CREATE` like so (omitting error/sanity checking):

```
ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE);

char sysfs_device_name[16];
ioctl(fd, UI_GET_SYSNAME(sizeof(sysfs_device_name)), sysfs_device_name);
printf("/sys/devices/virtual/input/%s\n", sysfs_device_name);
```

If it is not available, you can try looking up the sysfs device in `/proc/bus/input/devices` which should contain an entry like:

```
I: Bus=0006 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0001
N: Name="your-uinput-device-name"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd mouse0 event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0 0 7ffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: REL=143
```

..which is a bit messier. But as you can see it'll also give you a shortcut to the device created in `/dev/input`.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the /dev/input/event[n] file after the creation without reading from the filesystem? The new input device passthrough for qemu expects it like this -device virtio-input-host-pci,evdev=/dev/input/eventn

Answer (score 0):

I was in the boat of not having the `UI_GET_SYSNAME` function work for me (it executed, but returned nothing).  Also, I wanted the "event handler path" which is a different (though related) dynamic value.  As such, I forced into the ugliness of parsing the `/proc/bus/input/devices` file.

I posted my **bash** parser for this on the following StackExchange thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82064/how-to-get-the-actual-keyboard-device-given-the-output-of-proc-bus-input-device/507209#507209

That will fetch either of these values for you on demand...